# L.Routing.Control display directions individually

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am currently using L.Routing.Control to get directions between 2 waypoints, draw and route with custom DivIcons and display the directions in a box. It works great however it will be used on mobile devices and when in portrait mode the directions take up most of the display. I would like to either just display the next 1 or 2 directions or get the value of the next direction and display it in a somewhere else.

The code I have to load and display it is :

```
myroutewithout = L.Routing.control({
  waypoints: [
    L.latLng(window.my_lat, window.my_lng),
    L.latLng(window.job_p_lat, window.job_p_lng)
  ],show: true, units: 'imperial',
 router: L.Routing.mapbox('KEY-HERE'),
  createMarker: function(i, wp, nWps) {
    if (i === 0 || i === nWps + 1) {
      // here change the starting and ending icons
      return mymarker = L.marker(wp.latLng, {
        icon: window.operatorIcon
      });
    } else {
      // here change all the others
      return job_start = L.marker(wp.latLng, {
        icon: window.jobIcon
      }); 
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

And the image of it running in both portrait and landscape

[image: View in landscape][image: View in portrait]